# Hadoop WordCount giving 0 counts for all words

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm having trouble with the WordCount program in hadoop. The word count is not correct, it shows 0 for all the words, however all the distinct words are present in the output.

this is my sample data, loaded into hdfs

```
# filename: file01.txt
Hello World Bye World
```

and

```
# filename: file02.txt
Hello Hadoop Bye Hadoop
```

This is the source:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;


public class WordCount {
    public static class Map
            extends MapReduceBase
            implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {


        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable();
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable longWritable, Text value,
                        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,
                        Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                output.collect(word, one);
            }
        }
    }


    public static class Reduce
            extends MapReduceBase
            implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
                           OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,
                           Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            int sum = 0;
            while(values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JobConf jobConf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
        jobConf.setJobName("wordcount");

        jobConf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        jobConf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        jobConf.setCombinerClass(WordCount.Reduce.class);
        jobConf.setReducerClass(WordCount.Reduce.class);
        jobConf.setMapperClass(WordCount.Map.class);

        jobConf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        jobConf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(jobConf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(jobConf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(jobConf);
    }
}
```

When I run the jar the output file is generated in the output folder, but it shows the following:

```
$ bin/hdfs dfs -cat ./output/part-00000
17/11/09 02:50:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Bye 0
Hadoop  0
Hello   0
World   0
```

As you can see, all the counts are zero, however I can't find where I made the error in my implementation.

Comment: `mapred` API is deprecated. Please use packages according to your Hadoop version. I see you are using `hdfs dfs` command. I'll encourage you to use the newer `mapreduce` API.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah I have tried to Debug your code the error was in your Map class

```
 public static class Map
        extends MapReduceBase
        implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {


    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable();
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable longWritable, Text value,
                    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

> As your Mapper class was returning null(0) as Value ,so reducer was not able to reduce the value

- So initialise value 1 so that it will return value 1 for each word.

here is the code

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable();
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable longWritable, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            one.set(1);

            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }
```

It will work ....

Comment: Thanks. With your solution, I get the following counts: `Bye 2 Hadoop 2 Hello 0 World 2`. The count for `Hello` is incorrect. I was able to fix it by reversing the order of the lines `word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());` and `one.set(1)`. I'm using Hadoop version 2.8.1. Could you please update your answer for future readers of this post.